# ArcGIS Server REST-Query Layer: only few attribute fields are returned in response

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, query-layer, fields-attributes

A newbie question in using ArcGIS Server REST service:

From the ArcGIS Services Directory, I opened the page of one layer in a MapServer service, this layer has a long list of attributes/fields. However, in the response of **Query_Layer** operation, it only includes ***two attribute fields*** in each feature object.

I am wondering is this a configurable setting? If so, where to control this to return all attribute fields?

Let me if further details of this question are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Result Options box near the bottom of the page, there is an input for 'Return Fields (Comma Separated)'.  Accordingly, you put in a comma delimited list of the fields you want included.  Its the same thing for all of the web api's as well, there is a property where you set what fields get returned to the client.

I think by default, it only returns OBJECTID and Display Field.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs this in the requesturl, it is now called "outFields".
An example request:

> /arcgis/rest/services/ServicName/MapServer/0/query?objectIds=36&**outFields=***&returnGeometry=true&f=pjson

If you need all fields just use an asterisk.